# How to search duplicate strings in file using python and getting the last counted string dynamic way

Tags: python

I have file a.txt contains following repeated lines

```
a.txt
00 This is stack overflow line 0
01 This is stack overflow line 1
02 This is stack overflow line 2
03 This is stack overflow line 3
04 This is stack overflow line 4 forum is good
```

I tried with below code working in static way but able to get only count dynamic way

```
def readMultiple(logfile,searchString,countnumber):

    with open(logfile) as search:
        count=0

        for line in search:
            line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
            #print "Line", line

            if searchString in line:

                #print(line )
                  count+=1
                  print "count",count
                  if count==count:
                      #print "count linees ",line
                      print ""
    print "count line ",line

readMultiple("a.txt","This is stack overflow line",4)
```

Comment: `if count==count:` -- what's that supposed to check? _Typo?_

Comment: That's basically `if True:`... probably a typo @devnull

Comment: Actually I am checking static way but i need dynamic approach

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean in this context? I have no idea what you want to do differently than what you're already doing.

Comment: Here, dynamic means right now "a.txt" file contains only 5 duplicated lines if more than 5 lines then i am facing problem with last line finding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the variable count_number and it's dynamic, see code:

```
def readMultiple(logfile,searchString,countnumber):
    with open(logfile) as search:
        count=0
        for line in search:
            line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
            #print "Line", line

            if searchString in line:
                #print(line )
                count+=1
                print "count",count


readMultiple("a.txt","This is stack overflow line")
```